# MongoDB is going back to matching among all documents after $group stage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I have a collection looking like this:

```js
[
   {"url":"website.com/test", "links":[ {"url": "www.something.fr/page.html","scoreDiff": 0.44} ], "justUpdated": true, "score": 0.91},
   {"url":"domain.com/", "links":[], "justUpdated": true, "score": 0.81},
   {"url":"www.something.fr/page.html", "links":[], "justUpdated": false, "score": 0.42},
]
```

The goal here is to get the third document, because in one of the documents where "justUpdated" equals true (the first one here), there is its url as a value in one of the "links" array elements.

**To achieve that, I tried:**

To find all the documents with "justUpdated" equals to true, then in NodeJS concatenate all the urls in their "links" arrays (let's call this array `urlsOfInterest`). And finally do another query to find all the documents where the url is in `urlsOfInterest`.

The problem is that it takes some time to do the first query then process the result and do the second query.

So I thought maybe I could do it all at once in an aggregate query. I use `$group` (with `$cond` to check if `justUpdated` equals true) to get all the arrays of "links" in one new variable named `urlsOfInterest`. For now this is an array of arrays of object so I then use `$project` with `$reduce` to have all these `{url: "...", score: X}` objects as one big array. Finally I use `$project` and `$map` to only have the url as the score value doesn't interest me here.

So I get an output looking like this:

```js
   _id:"urlsOfInterest",
   urlsOfInterest: ["www.something.fr/page.html"]
```

Which is pretty great but I am stuck because now I just need to get the documents where `url` is in this variable named `urlsOfInterest` except I can't because all my documents have "disappeared" after the `$group` stage.

Please help me to find a way to perform this final query :) Or if this isn't the right way to do this, please point me in the right direction !

PS: the *real* goal here would be to update for all the documents where `justUpdated` equals true, every `scoreDiff` values in their `links` array. For our exemple, we do `abs(0.91 - 0.42) = 0.49` so we replace our `scoreDiff` value of 0.44 by 0.49 (0.91 being the score of the document where `justUpdated` equals true and 0.42 the score of the document where `url` equals `www.something.fr/page.html`, explaining why I need to fetch this last document.) I don't believe there could be a way of doing all of this at once but if there is, please tell me !

Comment: Don't overcomplicate, use $lookup to search documents with matching urls

Comment: @AlexBlex I don't see how this can help me as it is all in the same collection

Comment: That's okay to lookup the same collection

Comment: Are you saying that I dont' have to do the $group/$project and all I can't just use $lookup ? Could you please guide me on how to use it because it isn't clear to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get all matching documents in an array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "justUpdated": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "links.url",
      "foreignField": "url",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "result": {
        $gt: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Then either $unwind and $replaceRoot the `results` array to get the documents as a cursor and do the math on the application level or do the calculations in the same pipeline, e.g. with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

The "PS: the real goal" is not quite clear as it is based on a particular example but if you play a little bit with it [in the playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OD-0I3JhfC5) I am sure you can calculate the numbers as per your requirements.

Comment: It seems like a great solution but I can't get it to work, every "result" field is empty. Perhaps the "localField": "links.url" is incorrect as links is an array of objects and not an object itself ? But I don't know how to correct that...

Comment: Sorry Paul, did you follow the link to the playground? It clearly shows the results array contains the document you are after (you need to click the blue "run" to see the outcome in the right hand side panel). Could you validate if the source documents in the playground are similar to what you have? I copied them straight from the question.

Comment: I got it to work thank you, I just forgot a change I made in the meantime !